# Infinite loop when trying to add to the beginning of a linked list in C

Tags: c, linked-list

I'm trying to practice Linked Lists in C and I created a simple LL with an add function that takes a position index and inserts the data at that position.

I keep getting an infinite loop when trying to add to the beginning of my list using the `add_beg`, which just calls the `add_at` function with position 0 (`add(0, data)`) function. I can't seem to find the reason why this is happening. I need another set of eyes. Here is the code:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct node_t {
    int _data;
    struct node_t *_next;
} node_t;

node_t *_head = NULL;

void add_at(int pos, int data) {
    node_t *node = malloc(1 * sizeof(node_t));
    node->_data = data;
    node->_next = NULL;
    // insert if empty
    if (_head == NULL) {
        _head = node;
    }
    else {
        int index = 0;
        node_t *prev = NULL;
        node_t *curr = _head;
        while (curr != NULL && index != pos) {
            prev = curr;
            curr = curr->_next;
            index++;
        }
        // insert beginning
        if (index == 0) {
            _head = node;
            node->_next = _head;
        }
        // insert end
        else if (index != 0 && curr == NULL) {
            prev->_next = node;
        }
        // insert middle
        else {
            prev->_next = node;
            node->_next = curr;
        }
    }
}

void add_beg(int data) {
    add_at(0, data);
}

void add_end(int data) {
    add_at(-1, data);
}

void dump() {
    if (_head != NULL) {
        node_t *curr = _head;
        while (curr != NULL) {
            if (curr->_next != NULL) {
                printf("%d -> ", curr->_data);
            }
            else {
                printf("%d", curr->_data);
            }
            curr = curr->_next;
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    else {
        printf("The list is empty\n");
    }
}

int main() {
    add_beg(6);
    
    add_at(1, 1);
    add_at(2, 3);
    add_at(3, 9);
    add_at(4, 8);
    add_at(5, 5);
    add_at(7, 2);
    add_at(8, 4);

    add_beg(9); // commenting this out prevents the infinite loop

    dump();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This is one of those things where it's highly educational to walk through execution in a debugger.

Answer (score 4):

The error is in this section:

```
if (index == 0) {
    _head = node;
    node->_next = _head;
}
```

That second command sets `node->_next` to `head`.  However, the line before set `_head` to `node`.  Therefore, you just set `node->_next` to `node`, creating the infinite loop.

You need to reverse the order of those two statements.

Comment: @dunlop, did this answer your question?

Answer (score 0):

```
if (index == 0) {
        _head = node;
        node->_next = _head;
    }
```

here you set `_head` as `node` but after `next node` at `_head` then when your doing while loop you had already broke your linked list.

Fix :

first set the `_head` as `node->_next` then set `_head` as `node`